# Can a Windows .exe GUI application be converted to DLL, and then run the GUI?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

How can I convert a Visual-C++ GUI project from app to DLL, and then have a C# app call the DLL and run the GUI?

When I try, the " dlg.DoModal();"  causes "Debug Assertion Failed!".

I've got a visual studio 2010 C++ project with Config Props set for:
"Config Type is app (.exe)
Use MFC in a Shared DLL
Not Using ATL"

When I change it to DLL, select Common Lang Run Support (/clr), I can successfully call its individual functions from my C# solution.

I've tried calling a test function in the DLL that calls
"theApp.InitInstance();"
but this generates "Debug Assertion Failed!".

Comment: MFC gets very cranky when it isn't initialized properly.  It uses assertions to tell you about it.  Not documenting the assert message is a very unproductive way to ask questions about them.  You'll need to read the [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30c674tx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you tried to convert the Win32 application into .NET one with just one switch (/clr), and this won't work (well it can work but in very simple cases and not in yours).

You still can convert the EXE into Win32 unmanaged DLL (this requires writing a couple of extra lines in .def file and in the main code), then use P/Invoke to invoke that function.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty MFC DLL project and copy all the essential code from Exe into it. Just changing he project type in Visual Studio Settings won't correctly change all the other code that Wizard generates when you create DLL app from scratch.